# SQL, Get a list of all the custom data types

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, jdbc

I need to retrieve a list of all the user defined data types in sql(oracle and postgres) using either an sql command or jdbc.
For now I only know how to retrieve the source code with

```
SELECT text FROM all_source WHERE name='type'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle has a data dictionary view for almost everything.  You can select from
[ALL_TYPES](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2112.htm#sthref1504) and [ALL_TYPE_ATTRS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2109.htm#sthref1498).  The latter shows the owner of each type.

Postgres does not have the same functionality so you can use this query from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3703727/851930)

```
SELECT      n.nspname as schema, t.typname as type 
FROM        pg_type t 
LEFT JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = t.typnamespace 
WHERE       (t.typrelid = 0 OR (SELECT c.relkind = 'c' FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c WHERE c.oid = t.typrelid)) 
AND     NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_type el WHERE el.oid = t.typelem AND el.typarray = t.oid)
AND     n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM ALL_TYPES where owner='myusername' ,this seems to work,do you know any equivalent view in postgres?

Comment: @SteveL   Postgres does not have a view like Oracle.  You could always make your own for your convenience.